# multiple graph on different page and save as pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I have used `facet_wrap` function to make multiple graphs  but they all appear on one page. I looked lots of question but unfortunately have not succeed yet. if I could print this to 1 graph per page in a pdf, that would be great.
here is my data :

```
co1<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10,12,14,16,18), cn= c(10.1,12.1,14.25,16.09,18.3), country ="a")
co2<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.5,12.6,14.5,16.5,18.5), cn= c(10.6,12.5,14.3,16.7,18.6), country ="b")
co3<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.9,12.9,14.9,16.9,18.9), cn= c(11.9,13.9,15.9,17.9,19.9), country ="c")
df<- rbind(co1,co2,co3)
```

here is my code to make multiple graphs on one page:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age,group = country))+
  geom_line(aes(y=pop),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=cn),colour="blue")+
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  xlab("age") + ylab("population")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` you could do:

```
library(ggforce)
library(tibble)

co1<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10,12,14,16,18), cn= c(10.1,12.1,14.25,16.09,18.3), country ="a")
co2<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.5,12.6,14.5,16.5,18.5), cn= c(10.6,12.5,14.3,16.7,18.6), country ="b")
co3<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.9,12.9,14.9,16.9,18.9), cn= c(11.9,13.9,15.9,17.9,19.9), country ="c")
df<- rbind(co1,co2,co3)

pdf("multi_page.pdf", width = 16 / 2.54, height = 12 / 2.54)
lapply(seq_along(unique(df$country)), function(page) {
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age,group = country))+
    # If you want a legend: Map on aesthetics! 
    geom_line(aes(y=pop, colour="pop"))+
    geom_line(aes(y=cn,colour="cn"))+
    # Set the colors via scale_xxx_manual 
    scale_color_manual(values = c(pop = "blue", cn = "red")) +
    facet_wrap_paginate(~country, ncol = 1, nrow = 1, page = page) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
    xlab("age") + ylab("population")
})
dev.off()
```

Comment: thanks @stefan for your great answer. how can I add title for `cn` and `pop`?

Comment: Hej @mehmo. What you mean by title? A legend for the colors?

Comment: Hi @stefan. Yes exactly

Comment: Hi @mehmo. That was my thought. I just made an edit. As a general lesson you have to keep in mind: If you want a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. move `color=...` into `aes()` and set the colors via `scale_xxx_manual`. Best S.